# VkNet: Отправка сообщения от имени сообщества

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

Не могу отправить сообщества. В инете пишут, что возможно необходимо авторизоваться от имени сообщества, но я не понимаю как это сделать. Прошу Вашей помощи.

```
using System;
using VkNet;
using VkNet.Enums.Filters;
using VkNet.Exception;
using VkNet.Model;
using VkNet.AudioBypassService.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TestConnect
{
 public class Connector
 {
    public Connector(string login, string password)
    {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    private const long AppID = 7111965;

    private string login, password;

    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddAudioBypass();

            var api = new VkApi(services);
            api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
            {
                ApplicationId = AppID,
                Login = login,
                Password = password,
                Settings = Settings.All
            });

            int randomId = new Random().Next(1, int.MaxValue);

            Console.WriteLine(api.Messages.Send(new VkNet.Model.RequestParams.MessagesSendParams
            {
                RandomId = randomId,
                UserId = 223398928,
                Domain = "evgengorb",
                Message = "message"
            }));
        }
        catch (VkApiAuthorizationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("не правильный логин или пароль");
        }
        catch (VkApiException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поторопился с вопросом, разобрался. Может кому-то поможет.

Для того, чтобы отправлять сообщения от имени сообщества необходимо использовать параметр groupID:

```
Console.WriteLine(api.Messages.Send(new VkNet.Model.RequestParams.MessagesSendParams
            {
                RandomId = randomId,
                GroupId = ********,
                Domain = "evgengorb",
                Message = "message"
            })) ;
```